# How do I access MySQL console on wampserver 3?

Tags: mysql, wampserver

How do I access MySQL console on Wampserver 3?

With the earlier versions all you had to do was right click on the Wamp server icon and the option to access MySQL console shows up on the side but with Wampserver 3 I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

In WAMPServer 3, it is in the same place it has always been.

You left click the wampmanager icon in the system tray and you will see this menu appear

[image]

Just like before its called `MySQL console`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the MySQL console for Wampserver...

1. Run cmd command
2. Type `c:` or `d:` on command prompt. This will depend on where your wampserver is installed.
3. Assuming you have installed wamp on `D:` drive:
4. `D:\ > cd wamp`
5. `D:\wamp > cd bin`
6. `D:\wamp\bin > cd mysql`
7. `D:\wamp\bin\mysql > cd {whatever version of mysql is installed check folder}`
8. `D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.1.36 > cd bin`
9. `D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.1.36\bin > mysql.exe -u root`

These are the main steps to run MySQL on command line.

Source: https://bmehla.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/run-mysql-command-line-with-wamp/